# UIImageView on top of a UICollectionView

Tags: image, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionview

How would I be able to put an image to go over my existing collection view controller.

As seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyK8t.jpg

I need it to not affect scrolling or interactions with the uicollectionview, but I need to be able to interact with it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In interface builder, make sure the UIScrollView and your other UIView (UIButtons, UIImageViews are included) are two different entities of the same level, eg not nested in each other.

Give the second UIView a z-order so that it appears over the UIScrollView.

Comment: I only have one view currently, and that my UICollectionViewController.

Comment: Well, `UICollectionViewController` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.  the process doesn't change much. Add both of them programmatically, be sure they are of the same level (hierarchically speaking), and tweak their z-orders.